# Removing quotes in a Django template

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I have a Django template that looks like this:

```
 <div id="objects">
                <b>Ingredients:</b>
                <small>
                {% for obj in result.object.list_objects|slice:":10" %}
                    .{{ obj }}
                {% endfor %}
                ......
                </small>
              </div>
```

I am trying to output a simple list but when I loop through these elements in the template, the output is unfortunately in single quotes for each object. I am new to Django templates and have tried using a few methods like `safe` and `escape`. But the single quotes remain. Is there a way in Django to strip out that specific character when loading the data?

Comment: (a) Have you written [`__str__` methods](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/instances/#str) for your model? (b) Why are you passing `result` into your template? IMO you should slice and dice the list of objects in your view code and pass the list of ten objects you want directly to your template. (c) Is this your _exact_ code? I suspect it's not, since your `list_objects` contains a typo. Please edit your question and paste _exactly_ the code you are using. A single character can make a big difference.

Comment: Also, please show the data itself.

Answer (score 6):

This question looks a bit dated, but wanted to toss in a simple solution. You can make a custom template tag and use the replace function.

Example:

```
@register.filter
def strip_double_quotes(quoted_string):
    return quoted_string.replace('"', '')
```

{{ my_quoted_string|strip_double_quotes }}

Answer (score 3):

You can use

```
                {% for obj in result.object.list_objects %}
                    {{ obj|slice:"1:-1" }}
                {% endfor %}
```

Comment: add some description

Comment: This works, though is this the best way to acheive this. I'm passing json objects in context to be used in js, though on template they are rendered with double quotes...